Why are the rotators for N Cipher throw me a logic error?
The rotators are wrong
I tried to ask ChatGPT to fix it but it doesn't work
Here is the code btw:
`void NCipher()
{
    nLetters = new List<char>();
    nLet = new List<char>();
    for (int n = 0; n < 6; n++)
    {
        nLetters.Add(nWord[n]);
    }

    nRotators = "";

    // Rotate n4, n5, and n6
    char temp;
    List<int> indices1 = new List<int>() { n4, n5, n6 };
    indices1.Sort(); // Sort the indices in ascending order
    List<int> originalIndices1 = new List<int>(indices1); // Store the original indices for rotation

    for (int i = 0; i < indices1.Count; i++)
    {
        int newIndex = Rnd.Range(0, 6);
        while (indices1.Contains(newIndex))
        {
            newIndex = Rnd.Range(0, 6);
        }
        indices1[i] = newIndex;
    }

    // Rotate the letters while preserving the original order of rotation
    temp = nLetters[indices1[0]];
    nLetters[indices1[0]] = nLetters[originalIndices1[0]];
    nLetters[originalIndices1[0]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices1[0]];

    temp = nLetters[indices1[1]];
    nLetters[indices1[1]] = nLetters[originalIndices1[1]];
    nLetters[originalIndices1[1]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices1[1]];

    temp = nLetters[indices1[2]];
    nLetters[indices1[2]] = nLetters[originalIndices1[2]];
    nLetters[originalIndices1[2]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices1[2]];

    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Numbers are {1}{2}{3}", _moduleID, indices1[0], indices1[1], indices1[2]);
    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Letters after first rotation are {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}", _moduleID, nLetters[0], nLetters[1], nLetters[2], nLetters[3], nLetters[4], nLetters[5]);

    // Rotate n1, n2, and n3
    List<int> indices2 = new List<int>() { n1, n2, n3 };
    indices2.Sort(); // Sort the indices in ascending order
    List<int> originalIndices2 = new List<int>(indices2); // Store the original indices for rotation

    for (int i = 0; i < indices2.Count; i++)
    {
        int newIndex = Rnd.Range(0, 6);
        while (indices2.Contains(newIndex))
        {
            newIndex = Rnd.Range(0, 6);
        }
        indices2[i] = newIndex;
    }

    // Rotate the letters while preserving the original order of rotation
    temp = nLetters[indices2[0]];
    nLetters[indices2[0]] = nLetters[originalIndices2[0]];
    nLetters[originalIndices2[0]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices2[0]];

    temp = nLetters[indices2[1]];
    nLetters[indices2[1]] = nLetters[originalIndices2[1]];
    nLetters[originalIndices2[1]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices2[1]];

    temp = nLetters[indices2[2]];
    nLetters[indices2[2]] = nLetters[originalIndices2[2]];
    nLetters[originalIndices2[2]] = temp;
    nRotators += "FJNSVX"[indices2[2]];

    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Numbers are {1}{2}{3}", _moduleID, indices2[0], indices2[1], indices2[2]);
    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Letters after second rotation are {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}", _moduleID, nLetters[0], nLetters[1], nLetters[2], nLetters[3], nLetters[4], nLetters[5]);

    string nNewWord = "";
    for (int p = 0; p < 6; p++)
    {
        nNewWord += nLetters[p];
    }
    string indices;
    indices = "";
    for (int w = 0; w < 6; w++)
    {
        if (w < 3)
        {
            indices += indices1[w].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int q;
            q = w % 3;
            indices += indices2[q].ToString();
        }
    }
    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Numbers are {1}", _moduleID, indices);
    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Rotators are {1}", _moduleID, nRotators);
    Debug.LogFormat("[Copper-9 #{0}] N Cipher: Letters after rotating are {1}", _moduleID, nNewWord);
}

`
It does the cycle then it swaps n1/n4 with the first letter. What line makes the logic error? I just want to fix it. This is for a Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes modded module called Copper-9. Copper-9 is the planet where Murder Drones take place and the letters on the display will be like the murder drones.
